# How can you access redux's store from a non-component helper function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a a helper function that I call when I want to delete something from my redux store. However I need to be able to access the current store inside the function to make a determination on what to do next. Here's what I want to do:

```
export function deleteDocument (id) {
    this.props.dispatch(deleteShape({id}));

    const getStore = getStore(); //<-- I need something like this

    if(getStore.documents && !getStore.documents.find(doc => doc.selected)){
        this.props.dispatch(makeTopDocumentSelected());
    }
}
```

I call this function from  a component and pass the "this" context to it so it will have access to dispatch if you're curious about that. But if I try to reference a prop that I pass along it doesn't update after the "deleteShape" call because this function is not "connected" (for lack of a better word) to the redux store. So my question is this: how can I access the current redux store from non-component functions? Thanks

Comment: If you want to do it in Redux use action for it. If you want to do it from a React component dispatch the relevant action from componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Comment: How could I get the state from an action in this sense?

Comment: if you use a library like redux-thunk you can get state from an action like

myAction(input) {
   return function(dispatch, getState) {
       const state = getState();
   };
}

Comment: Do you always select the top document when deleting a document? If yes, why are you not just doing it in the reducer? This way you only call deleteShape and the top document gets selected and returned immediately.

Comment: Jon, I tried using your function but it just returns a function, not redux's store. Can you provide a bit more detailed example of how to use redux-thunk? I don't see any info about getting the the store in their docs.

Comment: Shouldn't you just dispatch an action with the selected doc (id?) in the payload and let a reducer evaluate the condition?

Answer (score 7):

I must say that I think it's a bad practice to randomly access the store from some function, and some side effects may occur, but if you have to do it this is a possible way:

file: storeProvider.js

```
var store = undefined;

export default {
    init(configureStore){
        store = configureStore();
    },
    getStore(){
        return store;
    }
};
```

file: App.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import storeProvider from './storeProvider';

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer);
storeProvider.init(configureStore);
const store = storeProvider.getStore();

const App = () =>
    <Provider store={store} >
        <Stuff/>
    </Provider>
```

file: yourfunction.js

```
import storeProvider from './storeProvider';

export function deleteDocument (id) {
    this.props.dispatch(deleteShape({id}));

    const state = storeProvider.getStore().getState();

    if(state.documents && !state.documents.find(doc => doc.selected)){
        this.props.dispatch(makeTopDocumentSelected());
    }
}
```

Comment: If `yourfunction.deleteDocument` is called within a reducer, you're out of luck. Redux throws and will tell you to pass it down.