# React Redux - accessing existing store in a helper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, store

I'm trying to get the store instance (store state) outside a react component, namely in a separate helper function. I have my reducer, my action, I have created a store in the most upper component.

```js
// configStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import generalReducers from '../reducers/generalReducers';

export default function configStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(generalReducers, initialState);
}

// index.js


import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configStore from './store/configStore';

const initialReduxStoreConfig = {
    unit: 'm2',
    language: 'en'
}

const store = configStore(initialReduxStoreConfig);

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>    
    </Provider>
), document.querySelector('#root'));

// helpers.js

import configStore from '../store/configStore';

const store = configStore();

function getTranslation(key, lang = null) {
  console.log(store.getState());
}
```

This approach is not working as console.log(store.getState()) returns undefined. However, if I pass an initialConfig to configStore() it builds a new store and everything works just fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can move store initialization code into separate module, export store and import it whereever you need to use it.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I'm creating the store in a separate file, I'm calling the configStore() function in index.js

Comment: Take a look at my answer below for example solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code is not working because you're creating separate stores into `index.js` and `helpers.js` while you should use same Redux store.

You can move store initialization code into separate module, export store and import it whereever you need to use it.

```
// configStore.js
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import generalReducers from '../reducers/generalReducers';

export default function configStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(generalReducers, initialState);
}

// store.js
import configStore from './store/configStore';

const initialReduxStoreConfig = {
    unit: 'm2',
    language: 'en'
}

const store = configStore(initialReduxStoreConfig);

export default store;

// index.js
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
), document.querySelector('#root'));

// helpers.js
import store from './store';

function getTranslation(key, lang = null) {
    console.log(store.getState());
}
```

Comment: Put comment on similar [question+response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862357/how-can-you-access-reduxs-store-from-a-non-component-helper-function) - if you call `getTranslation` while inside a reducer - redux isn't going to like it. Throws error asking you to pass it down