# Connect a helper function to react-redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I exposed a bundle of helper functions in `helpers.js` , is there a way that I can make all my functions in helpers.js aware of the redux store?

I understand normally if its in a class Component, I could use export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName) so that state is mapped to my props.

I'm also trying to avoid direct access from `redux.store` or expose store globally.

This is not a duplication of [React Redux - accessing existing store in a helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951562/react-redux-accessing-existing-store-in-a-helper-function) 
solution to the answer exported store, which I don't have control of that.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: In which context, your helpers will be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Redux - accessing existing store in a helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951562/react-redux-accessing-existing-store-in-a-helper-function)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use case for the helper functions? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why a helper function would need access to the store directly instead of just passing in the data you need to your helper function to manipulate and send the new data back.

Comment: How about passing your helper functions through an HOC (higher-order-component) and inject the store to them via that HOC?